# Displaying date and time with slashes

Tags: php, date-format

In my database I have these columns:
`id, user, regdate`

To give an example:

```
1 Myuser 2013-03-12 07:48:00
```

How could I format the date using PHP and PDO to display it as:

`12/03/2013 07:48:00`

Comment: PDO doesn't format your data

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime('2013-03-12 07:48:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to declare your date format as a constant and then use in the whole application

```
echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime("2013-03-12 07:48:00"));
```

but make sure you dont rely on system time zone